# Android collapsible toolbar not working

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm trying to make a collapsible toolbar in android. I want the image to collapse when the user scrolls.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.mridulahuja.kudamm" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mridulahuja.kudamm.activities.ProductInfoActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/splash_background"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:minHeight="100dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Title");
```

It shows me this on android studio:

[image]

But when I run it, it just shows me this:

[image]

I've even tried to use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` but it didn't work either.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ???

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of NestedScrollView to Wrap_content instead of match_parent, it is occupyig entire screen. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.